# Can one modify the templates created by artisan migrate command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I've created a base class for my migrations. At the moment I run the artisan migrate command and it creates a new migration that extends the Migrations file, however I want to include my BaseMigration and extend it from there. I've been making this changes manualy but I feel like I'm repeating myself unnecessarily.

Any advice on how to have new migrations automatically extend and load my base migration?

Comment: If anyone is interested I made a package that solves this problem L5+ https://github.com/Kyslik/artisan-stubs

Comment: Its worth noting Laravel 7 solves this problem in a much more straightforward way.  See answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/61772765/6244

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can, because Laravel takes migrations from the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/stubs` folder and you cannot change that, but you have some options:

1) Create your own artisan command `migrate:makemyown`.

2) Use [Jeffrey Way's Laravel Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended). They let you create your migrations by doing:

```
php artisan generate:migration create_posts_table --fields="title:string, description:text"
```

If you just have some fields you need to start with and not something more specific than that, it works really fine.

3) Edit Laravel stubs, but the problem is that as soon as you `composer update` they might get overwritten by Composer.

Comment: I would highly recommend Jeffrey Way's Laravel Generators. The link above is broken and you should probably be using his version 5 generators which can be found [here](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended).

Comment: @Antonio "folder and you cannot change that" You explained *how* to change it in Option #3, so this earlier sentence adds unnecessary ambiguity. I'd probably combine Number 3 into your intro paragraph with the caveat that you will lose changes upon running `composer update`. This would be much more clear to readers. Thanks for the answer btw!

Answer (score 14):

It's doable in a fairly logical way, at least in Laravel 5

Subclass `MigrationCreator` and override `getStubPath()`, just copying the function over from the original class (it will use your subclass's `__DIR__`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator;

class AppMigrationCreator extends MigrationCreator
{
    public function getStubPath()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/stubs';
    }
}
```

Write a service provider to override `migration.creator` with your own subclass (it must be a **deferred** service provider, because you cannot override a deferred binding with an eager one):

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppMigrationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('migration.creator', function ($app) {
            return new AppMigrationCreator($app['files']);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['migration.creator'];
    }
}
```

Add your service provider to `config/app.php` **after** the default ones.

Finally, copy `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/stubs` alongside your MigrationCreator subclass (in this example it would become `app/Database/stubs`) and edit the templates to your needs.

Keep the `DummyClass` and `DummyTable` names, as they are replaced with `str_replace()` to create the actual migrations files.

Comment: It is doable in a fairly logical way. Don't know if I would call it "pretty easy" though :)

Comment: Note that the class name `AppMigrationServiceProvider` is very important, because Laravel seems to fail handling my own `MigrationServiceProvider`. Yes, even its namespace is certainly different from the built-in one's...

Comment: @Tobia `getStubPath()` has changed to `stubPath()`.

Comment: You may need to execute `php artisan config:cache` after that to update your `app.providers` cache.

Answer (score 14):

Since Laravel 7 you can [publish stubs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#stub-customization) using `php artisan stub:publish`.

> The published stubs will be located within a `stubs` directory in the root of your application. Any changes you make to these stubs will be reflected when you generate their corresponding classes using Artisan `make` commands.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there is no way to override this (for now) but I think that you can create your custom command which will use Laravel logic. This was created for Laravel 5.

First you have to create Generator command `app/Console/Commands/Generator.php`:

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class Generator extends Command
{

  /**
   * Command name
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $name = 'generate';

  /**
   * Command description
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $description = 'Custom object generator';

  /**
   * An array with all available generator classes
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $types = ['request', 'model', 'middleware'];

  /**
   * Execute command
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle()
  {
      $type = $this->argument('type');
      if (!in_array($type, $this->types)) {
          return $this->error('Type must be one of: '.implode(', ', $this->types));
      }

      // Create new instance
      $generatorClass = 'App\Console\Commands\Generators\\'.ucfirst($type);
      $generator = new $generatorClass(new Filesystem());

      // Each generator has "fire" method
      $this->comment($generator->setClassName($this->argument('name'))->fire());
  }

  /**
   * @return array
   */
  public function getArguments()
  {
      return [
          ['type', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Type of class to generate: '.implode(', ', $this->types)],
          ['name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Name of class to generate'],
      ];
  }

}
```

Then you have to create an abstract class for all of your Generators classes `app/Console/Commands/Generators/Generator.php`:

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands\Generators;

use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;

abstract class Generator extends GeneratorCommand
{
  // Directory name with whole application (by default app)
  const APP_PATH = 'app';

  /*
   * Name and description of command wont be used
   * Generators Commands are not loaded via Kernel
   * Name and description property has been put just to avoid Exception thrown by Symfony Command class
   */
  protected $name = 'fake';
  protected $description = 'fake';

  /**
   * Class name to generate
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $className;

  /**
   * Returns class name to generate
   *
   * @return string
   */
  protected function getNameInput()
  {
      return $this->className;
  }

  /**
   * Returns path under which class should be generated
   *
   * @param string $name
   * @return string
   */
  protected function getPath($name)
  {
      $name = str_replace($this->getAppNamespace(), '', $name);

      return self::APP_PATH.'/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $name).'.php';
  }

  /**
   * Sets class name to generate
   *
   * @param string $name
   * @return $this
   */
  public function setClassName($name)
  {
      $this->className = $name;
      return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Execute command
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function fire()
  {
      $name = $this->parseName($this->getNameInput());

      if ($this->files->exists($path = $this->getPath($name)))
      {
          return $this->type.' already exists!';
      }

      $this->makeDirectory($path);

      $this->files->put($path, $this->buildClass($name));

      return $this->type.' '.$this->className.' created successfully.';
  }

}
```

At the end you can create your first Generator class! `app/Console/Commands/Generators/Request.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands\Generators;

class Request extends Generator
{

  /**
   * Class type to generate
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $type = 'Request';

  /**
   * Returns default namespace for objects being generated
   *
   * @param string $rootNamespace
   * @return string
   */
  protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
  {
      return $rootNamespace.'\Http\Requests';
  }

  /**
   * Returns path to custom stub
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getStub()
  {
      return base_path('resources').'/stubs/request.stub';
  }

}
```

Dont forget to add your generate command to Kernel `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

  /**
   * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $commands = [
    ...
    'App\Console\Commands\Generator',
    ...
  ];
```

Put your stubs under `resources/stubs` directory. Let's create first one for Request Generator `resources/stubs/request.stub`:

```
<?php namespace {{namespace}};

class {{class}} extends Request
{

  /**
   * @return bool
   */
  public function authorize()
  {
    // CUSTOM LOGIC

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    $rules = [];

    // CUSTOM LOGIC

    return $rules;
  }

}
```

Then call with `php artisan generate request MyRequest`.

You can create your custom Model, Middleware, Controller etc. generators, it's very simple - you have to create new generator class under `app/Commands/Console/Generators` - take a look at `Request.php` generator to see how it works!

Answer (score -4):

For Laravel 5 you'd edit one of the `.stub` files in:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/stubs
```

There's no reason why you can't edit those files.

Search in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/` for `.stub` files to find all of the other stubs (templates) artisan uses.

Comment: That is a bad practice and you should really avoid editing libraries that you don't own. For example, if there is a new version of the Laravel and you want to update to it, then you cant really do it without losing the changes you have made.

Comment: You should override the file and not update the original files from vendor as it will be overridden by the updates of Laravel. You don't want to update the .stub everytime Laravel updates.