# Change default directory for creating migration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-8

I want to change the default directory for creating migration i.e. If I do `php artisan make:migration create_users_table`, it should create users table in `/database/migrations/child_database`. I do not want to use --path every time I create a migration for child_database. I want to change the default directory for `php artisan make:migration`.

Answer (score 0):

try this package [github repo](https://github.com/nscreed/laravel-migration-paths) or use [laracast link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/migration-from-different-folder)

You can use loadMigrationsFrom() in your AppServiceProvider.

Inside the boot() function, run:

```php
/**
 * Register Custom Migration Paths
 */
$this->loadMigrationsFrom([
    database_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'migrations'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'folder1',
    database_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'migrations'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'folder2',
]);/
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before, even though it's a little bit old it still has it's value.
Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895106

If you use this answer, the default directory is changed and you will have the solution you want.